# How to set up a node on Testnet of Lightning network on the world map

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network

I am currently having problems posting my node on the "World Map." I can see my node on the "Force Map" on [this site](https://explorer.acinq.co/#/faq).
Can anyone tell me how to enter the public IP so that it can be seen on the "World Map"?
My node is currently showing the pubkey but not the public IP.

Can anyone help me with steps of how to enter the IP of my node?

Comment: Is your node have at least one open channel?

Comment: Yes, it has 4 open channels.

Comment: Is your node expose a public IP and channel has 6 confirmations?

Comment: Just want to know how can i enter ip address of my node . I am using "lightning.exe" app , to make channels.

Comment: No ,we are not able to set our public IP .

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your lightning server with --externalip flag set to your public IP address. The specific command depends on which implementation you are using at the moment one of lnd, c-lightning or acinq.