# How to give IP to my node on the Bitcoin Lightning Network

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cash, lightning-network

I want to give Ip address to my new node . I have got the pubkey for my node , on the lightning.exe application ,but could not set IP address to my node so that it can be seen publicly on the site "https://explorer.acinq.co/#/faq". I have already created 4 channels also but need way to enter IP address.

Comment: You shouldn't spam with the same question. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69868/how-to-set-up-a-node-on-testnet-of-lightning-network-on-the-world-map

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on getting your Lightning Node up!

To get your server's external IP, you could try the following command/service:

```
$ curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/
```

The response will be your external IP. For example `123.123.123.123`.

---

**Example Configuration for C-Lightning**

Once you have the external IP, add it to the Lightning configuration. You can set the IP with the `ipaddr` command as follows:

```
$ lightningd --ipaddr=123.123.123.123
```

Note: You may need to stop lightningd before making this change.

Additionally, you can set the 'ip' property in the ['.lightning/config' file](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning#configuration-file).

Comment: Better to use a static IP or a hostname if you can.

Comment: Thanks, @surjikal. I completely agree, using a hostname provides coverage for a bunch of situations. However, I'm not sure that hostnames are currently supported. Are you able to confirm that hostnames work with C-Lightning?

Comment: I am not sure either, it would be cool but maybe there's some security issue with hostnames.. good question for IRC.